python duplicated row in a group
I need a function, or a sentence, to identify duplicated rows in a group.
For example, if we have this dataframe, grouping by column ID 1, I need see if values of ID 2 are duplicated within its group, or not:



ID 1
ID 2




A
1


A
2


A
2


A
2


B
11


B
12



the desired output should be:



ID 1
ID 2
Duplicated_ID 2_in_its_group(ID 1)




A
1
false


A
2
true


A
2
true


A
2
true


B
11
false


B
12
false



Ideally, define a function. If not, a sentence to apply to the whole dataframe.
Thanks.
I tried a function with no result. Sorry.

What have you already tried? Can you share a minimal reproduceable example with data?

Please use:
df.groupby('ID 1')['ID 2'].transform(lambda x: x.duplicated(keep=False))

By setting keep on False, all duplicates are True.
Reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html
Sample Code:
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID 1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
        'ID 2': [1, 2, 2, 2, 11, 12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Duplicated_ID_2_in_its_group(ID_1)'] = df.groupby('ID 1')['ID 2'].transform(lambda x: x.duplicated(keep=False))

print(df)

Output:
  ID 1  ID 2  Duplicated_ID_2_in_its_group(ID_1)
0    A     1                               False
1    A     2                                True
2    A     2                                True
3    A     2                                True
4    B    11                               False
5    B    12                               False



Group the DataFrame by ID 1
Check for duplicates within each group in ID 2using duplicated.
Mark the duplicated value as True and the non-duplicated as False.

Implementation:
import pandas as pd
def identify_duplicates(df):
    df['Duplicated_ID_2_in_its_group'] = df.groupby('ID 1')['ID 2'].transform(lambda x: x.duplicated(keep=False))
    return df
data = {
    'ID 1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
    'ID 2': [1, 2, 2, 2, 11, 12]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
result_df = identify_duplicates(df)
print(result_df)

